# Bootstrap - navbar scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a navbar using Bootstrap [using this](http://www.bootply.com/69848!) .
The problem is when I scroll the page and the navbar goes to top because the page jumps in down in the content!
Un
How can I resolve it?

[If you try to a little scroll from here, the page jumps under "Content"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrFX2.jpg)

Comment: I assume you mean your sidebar and navbar are not synced? update the code that sets the affix or the navbar to include the selector for the sidebar. ie [this updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Ul0vAszLAf) `$('#nav, #sidebar').affix(...)`

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @haxxxton Sorry, I was referring to the content

Comment: I am not sure what you're referring to then, the content scrolls nicely for me. Could you explain with pictures or try to describe what you're experiencing further please

Comment: @haxxxton look the edit

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean that when #nav is fixed to the top, the first bit of the "content" section gets hidden behind it? In that case the quickest fix I can think of would be to put some padding to the top of the content section.

```
.content {
  padding-top: 50px;
  }
```